# Qt Server Client Code

Tags: c++, linux, qt, sockets

I am a new to the QT programming. my server/client codes are quite simple but they are not working.......

pls have a look to find problems in my codes, thanks.

SERVER:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
//  QApplication app(argc, argv);
//      Server server;
        QTcpSocket *client_sock =  NULL;
        QTcpServer server;
        server.listen(QHostAddress::Any,8888);
        char buff[100];

    while(1)
    {
            if(server.hasPendingConnections())
            {
                    client_sock = server.nextPendingConnection();
            }
            if(client_sock)
            {
                    qint64 n_rtn;
                    n_rtn = client_sock->bytesAvailable();
                    client_sock->readLine(buff,n_rtn);
                    std::cout<<buff;
            }
    }
//  return app.exec();
}
```

CLIENT:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
//  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QTcpSocket client;
  QHostAddress addr("127.0.0.1");
  client.connectToHost(addr,8888);

  if(client.isWritable())
  {
        client.write("Hello World!\n");
  }

  client.close();

//  return app.exec();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Define *"not working"*.  What does it do? What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a QApplication or a QCoreApplication and an app.exec() nothing will work. This is what runs the event loop which handles all the keyboard/mouse/network events.

Take a look at the chat and fortune cookie [network server examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/examples-network.html) to see how to do this - it's almost as simple as the code you have written

Comment: curious...why does the OP have them in the code yet commented? I assume the OP tried them uncommented?

Comment: I assume they copied from the examples and commented out code that they didn't understand. If you are new to gui programming it's odd that the app 'sticks' in the last statement rather than in your code

Comment: while(1) is used instead of the event loop i think. can someone copy my code to have a test on his machine to find out the problem?

Comment: this is a backend program, its nothing to do with the GUI.

Comment: @mzzhmh the use  QCoreApplication - it still needs an event loop to repsond to network and other system events. You can't use while(1) because the OS has to talk to the Qt app